# Wifi uplink air interface

Tags: wireless, wifi, mobile

Most Wifi 802.11 standards use OFDM to achieve high data rates wirelessly. However, I was told OFDM is not suitable for uplink as it requires expensive and inefficient amplifiers which are not applicable in phones. Hence, LTE only uses OFDMA in downlink and SC-FDMA in uplink.

What is used in Wifi uplink communication? If OFDM is used, why is suitable here? If not, what else is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wifi is fully symmetrical meaning up- and downlink signals are identical. Both are OFDM modulated and on a fixed channel.

In Wifi the allowed transmitter power level is much smaller (a factor 10 or so) so efficiency of the PA (Power Amplfier) is less of an issue.

Note that SC-FDMA still uses OFDM but for a single channel only !
I guess that this is done so that the bandwith of the PA in the handset can be less, making it more efficient.

Comment: I don't really understand what you said about SC-FDMA. It uses OFDM but groups multiple subcarriers together to send the same symbol. This makes it somewhat similar to regular FDMA and avoids the many independent subcarriers which cause the high power variations in OFDM, right? Thus, allowing for more efficient and cheaper amplifiers.

Comment: SC-FDMA is a scheme where you can have multiple access **BUT** instead of OFDM which would need more channels (carriers) SC-FDMA only needs one channel (one carrier). In the channel there are still more subchannels but in SC-FDMA users can share that same channel. Indeed the power variations are smaller so lower performance amplifiers can be used.